# When I hover "a" my "id" gain hover too

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to my text and image gain white color at the same time, when one of them is on hover.

How `#btnicon` can gain `:hover`, when `li a` is `:hover`?

```
li a {  
    transition: .7s ease-out;
    color: #9d9d9d;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size:20px;
}

li a:hover{ 
    transition: .7s ease-out;
    color: #FFFFFF
}

#btnicon{
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    transition: .7s ease-out;
}

#btnicon:hover{
    transition: .7s ease-out;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(200%);
}
```

```
    <li><a href="index.html"><img id="btnicon"src="http://s11.postimg.org/bqc94ncoj/home.png">Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the image is in inside `a` you can do this:

```css
li a:hover #btnicon {
    transition: .7s ease-out;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(200%);
}
```

Comment: Yeaah, thats it! Thank you ^_^